# Help finding a logo I remember but can't find

Tags: logo, identity

I'm trying to find a logo I remember. I think it was for as courier company and it was a mythical/classical style face profile graphic of a man with headdress flowing. [image]

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that pops into my head would be FTD:

[image]

Comment: I was about to say how much that logo reminded me of the Interflora logo—but apparently that's because it _is_ the Interflora logo, Interflora being simply the international brand name (through a merger). Huh.

Answer (score 0):

The greek god Hermes is my first thought, he was the messenger between the gods. But the only thing I can find vaguely relevant would be this: [image]